# Adding rows to make a full long dataset for longitudinal data analysis

Tags: r, addition, rows, lme4, longitudinal

I am working with a long-format longitudinal dataset where each person has 1, 2 or 3 time points. In order to perform certain analyses I need to make sure that each person has the same number of rows even if it consists of NAs because they did not complete the certain time point.

Here is a sample of the data before adding the rows:

```
structure(list(Values = c(23, 24, 45, 12, 34, 23), P_ID = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 3), Event_code = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1), Site_code = c(1, 
1, 3, 3, 3, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))


This is the data I aim to get after adding the relevant rows:


structure(list(Values = c(23, 24, NA, 45, 12, 34, 23, NA, NA), 
P_ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), Event_code = c(1, 2, 
3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), Site_code = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I want to come up with code that would automatically add rows to the dataset conditionally on whether the participant has had 1, 2 or 3 visits. Ideally it would make rest of data all NAs while copying Participant_ID and site_code but if not possible I would be satisfied just with creating the right number of rows.

Comment: Just a name for the data frame I want to do this to.

Comment: I could also work straight with a csv file if there is way.

Comment: I am sorry. I saw that my attempt to visualise the dataset failed - I uploaded a picture now of how the first variables/columns look like. These is more data to the right but the key is in taking the event_code for each participant and making sure there are rows for all 3 events for each participant even if no data present.

Comment: I created a small sample: dput(sample)
structure(c(23, 24, 45, 12, 34, 23, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1), .Dim = c(6L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Values", "P_ID", "Event_code", "Site_code")))

Comment: Does this work?

Comment: Sorry, my actual data is data frame here:

Comment: structure(list(Values = c(23, 24, 45, 12, 34, 23), P_ID = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 3), Event_code = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1), Site_code = c(1, 
1, 3, 3, 3, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

Comment: Yes, because there are 3 events. The events are not represented by dates but integers. Like experiment 1, 2, 3.

Comment: I have now added my sample data frame to the post.

Comment: I have now added the desired dataset: structure(list(Values = c(23, 24, NA, 45, 12, 34, 23, NA, NA), 
    P_ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), Event_code = c(1, 2, 
    3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), Site_code = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
    1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `fill` after doing a `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
ExpandedDataset %>% 
      complete(P_ID, Event_code) %>%
      fill(Site_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came with quite a long code, but you could group it in a function and make it easier:
Here's your dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(rep("P1", 2), rep("P2", 3), "P3"),
                 Event = c("baseline", "visit 2", "baseline", "visit 2", "visit 3", "baseline"),
                 Event_code = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1),
                 Site_code = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1))
```

How many records you have per ID?

```
values <- summary(df$ID)
```

What is the maximum number of records for a single patient?

```
target <- max(values)
```

Which specific patients have less records than the maximum?

```
uncompliant <- names(which(values<target))
```

And how many records do you have for those patients who have missing information?

```
rowcount <- values[which(values<target)]
```

So now, let's create the vectors of the data frame we will add to your original one. First, IDs:

```
IDs <- vector()
for(i in 1:length(rowcount)){
  y <- rep(uncompliant[i], target - rowcount[i])
  IDs <- c(IDs, y)
}
```

And now, the sitecodes:

```
SC <- vector()
for(i in 1:length(rowcount)){
  y <- rep(unique(df$Site_code[which(df$ID == uncompliant[i])]), target - rowcount[i])
  SC <- c(SC, y)
}
```

Finally, a data frame with the values we will introduce:

```
introduce <- data.frame(ID = IDs, Event = rep(NA, length(IDs)),
                        Event_code = rep(NA, length(IDs)),
                        Site_code = SC)
```

Combine the original dataframe with the new values to be added and sort it so it looks nice:

```
final <- as.data.frame(rbind(df, introduce))
final <- final[order(v$ID), ]
```